# Python Lambda used to copy large files

Tags: python-2.7, lambda, boto3

I put together a simple Lambda function in python2.7 that would trigger when a file was places in a bucket. I later found out that files expected to be sent to the bucket I watched could be larger then 5GB (~490GB is the record found). So update the function with a different copy function. However the edits I've made now produce a issue with the event trigger.

What could be causing the error when the other copy function is used?
Any ways to improve this for the <500GB files come along?

Original script with 5GB copy limitation:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import json
import boto3
import time
import urllib
import re

print("Loading sftp file mover. Fuction= dev-sftp-move-lambda")
s3 = boto3.client('s3')             #for s3 copy function
s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')  #for s3 delete function

.... checks for fileparts and other stuff...

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    source_bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    key = urllib.unquote_plus(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'])
    target_bucket = 'dev-sftpinput'
    copy_source = {'Bucket':source_bucket,'Key':key}
    try:
        s3.copy_object(Bucket=target_bucket, Key=key, CopySource=copy_source, ServerSideEncryption='AES256')
    except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    print('Error in execution')
    raise
```

To allow for larger files I tried simply replacing the copy line with:

```
s3_resource.meta.client.copy( Bucket=target_bucket, Key=key, CopySource=copy_source, ExtraArgs={'ServerSideEncryption':'AES256'})
```

Error produced:

```
'Records': KeyError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 19, in lambda_handler
    source_bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
KeyError: 'Records'
```

Comment: `event` does not have an element for the key `'Records'`.

Comment: @ScottHunter, I'll try running it without `Records`. But why would I get the error when using `s3_resource.copy` but no error when using `s3.copy_object`?

Comment: I don't see `s3_resource.copy` anywhere within the posted code.